# API POST response returning 400 response code in Jmeter

Tags: json, api, jmeter, http-post, performance-testing

I am trying to create a test plan using jmeter.its for an API Post request, I have  a header manager, bodydata, checked for spellings and the syntax seems to be correct. However, Im getting 400 response code with the following error shown in the attached image. Anyone with an idea how I can resolve this? Thank you. [the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Exq7.png)
Here is the request [the request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtV1z.png)

The user doesn't have to be logged in, i have added a header manager, I have also noticed there header has a cookie value thats hard coded but it appears to be the same in every request. In the UI the API request returns 200 and thats what im expecting with the Jmeter script.

Answer (score 0):

In its current form the question cannot be answered comprehensively.

HTTP Status Code 400 means [that](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1)

> The 400 (Bad Request) status code indicates that the server cannot or
> will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be
> a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request
> message framing, or deceptive request routing).

1. Check that your `${site}` and `${csVersion}` variables have their respective values using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter)
2. Cross check [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) sent by JMeter and by the "UI", the most important is [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type)
3. Use a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) of [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and capture the requests which are being sent by JMeter and the "UI", the requests must be exactly the same apart from dynamic parameters which need to be [correlated](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have checked the syntax and the variables and everything checks out, I have also used blazemeter to capture the requests and its still the same response. The requests have an anti-forgery cookie which is different for each request, could this be whats causing the issue?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean by point 3, JMeter can handle cookies automatically using [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-cookie-manager) but you need to open the page first or whatever your "UI" does, your JMeter test needs to exactly simulate "UI" network footprint.

Comment: Thank you for answering this question. The issue was in a cookie value in the header, I ended up using a regex to extract it from the previous request and called it in the request that was failing and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

The issues was being caused by an anti-forgery cookie which was hard coded in the request.I used a regex to extract the value from a previous request and used a variable value from the regex to make sure the same value is being passed on to the request that was failing.